# Whether to post solidity & smart contract questions on SO or Ethereum SE?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm conflicted about where these questions belong and/or where they will be better received. A glance at the Ethereum SE's top questions clearly shows most of them are programming-related. The community is much smaller so answers may be slower to come & fewer in number but *may* be higher in quality.

Anyone have guidance on where/when to post to one site over the other?

Comment: Sounds like it has less to do with blockchain technology outright and more to do with Ethereum itself, so I'd be *tempted* to say it belongs over there.